# Error when changing custom object name field from text to auto

Tags: error

I am getting the following error when trying to change a custom object's name field from text to auto.

Unable to Access Page
The value of a parameter contains a character that is not allowed or the value exceeds the maximum allowed length. Remove the character from the parameter value or reduce the value length and resubmit. If the error still persists, report it to our Customer Support team. Provide the URL of the page you were requesting as well as any other related information. I am using Lightning.

Comment: What did you use for the auto-number format and starting number? This error sometimes happens if you have invalid input.

Comment: I have tried a variety of options for the starting #.  For example, I tried A-{0000} with 0 as a starting number.  I tried the date option of {YYYY}{MM}-{0} with a starting number of 0.  I changed the staring numbers various times and none worked.  I want to mention that the data type was auto-number until yesterday when I switched it to text to see if I wanted to use it.  I have several hundred records with the A-{0000} format already.  I don't have any with the text format since I deleted my test records that used that format.